# structure members in different gcc version

Tags: c++, templates, memory-alignment, pack

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack(1)
struct Foo
{
    uint8_t f1;
    uint8_t f2;
    uint32_t f3;
};

struct Bar
{
    uint64_t b1;
    Foo b2;
    bool b3;
};

template<typename BT1, typename BT2, bool BT3= false>
class BarTemplate
{
public:
    BT1 bt1;
    BT2 bt2;
    bool bt3;
};
#pragma pack()

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "compile ver: " << __VERSION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof Foo: " << sizeof(Foo) << std::endl;
    typedef BarTemplate<uint64_t, Foo> BarT;
    std::cout << "sizeof BarTemplate<uint64_t, Foo>: " << sizeof(BarT) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof Bar: " << sizeof(Bar) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this code has diff output in gcc 4.4.6 and gcc 4.8.

compile ver: 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
sizeof Foo: 6
sizeof BarTemplate: 16
sizeof Bar: 15

compile ver: 4.8.2
sizeof Foo: 6
sizeof BarTemplate: 15
sizeof Bar: 15

what is difference between gcc 4.4 and 4.8 with pack members in template ?

Comment: Try moving the `#pragma pack()` to after the `main` function, see if that changes the behavior. If so, then the issue is that the different versions disagree on when the packing for a template takes effect. (It could be at template declaration time or at instantiation time.) Since `#pragma pack` is not covered by the standard, different compilers are permitted to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because gcc Memory Alignment, compiler expect the memory allocat size is 4 byte Integer multiples.
but gcc 4.8 not do that.

Comment: But non-template has the same result。

Answer (score 0):

diffrent version gcc compiler explent pragma pack() to diffrent code
my gcc 4.4.7 code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack(1)
struct Foo
{
   uint8_t f1;
   uint8_t f2;
   uint32_t f3;
};

struct Bar
{
  uint64_t b1;
  Foo b2;
  bool b3;
 };
 #pragma pack(1)

 template<typename BT1, typename BT2, bool BT3= false>
 class BarTemplate
 {
   public:
   BT1 bt1;
   BT2 bt2;
   bool bt3;
 };

 int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
 {
     std::cout << "compile ver: " << __VERSION__ << std::endl;
     std::cout << "sizeof Foo: " << sizeof(Foo) << std::endl;
     typedef BarTemplate<uint64_t, Foo> BarT;
     std::cout << "sizeof BarTemplate<uint64_t, Foo>: " << sizeof(BarT) <<           std::endl;
     std::cout << "sizeof Bar: " << sizeof(Bar) << std::endl;

     return 0;
 }
```

result:

```
compile ver: 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
sizeof Foo: 6
sizeof BarTemplate<uint64_t, Foo>: 15
sizeof Bar: 15
```

Comment: 哇擦，这是啥回事？-fpack-struct貌似也没啥用